# how do I extract the 5th bit of a byte in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

If I have the decimal `12`, its representation in binary is `00001100`. How do I extract the **fifth** bit, which in this case is `1`? I tried *shifting left* by `4` and `AND`-ing with `1` but this is *not correct*. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
player = low << 4 & 1;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Comment: Do you mean the fifth bit _counting from the left_?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, counting from the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually want to obtain **3d bit** (starting from the *right end*):

```
 00001100
     ^
     3d from the right end (bits are zero based)
```

All you have to do is to get rid of `3` lower bits (`100`) with a help of `>>` and check the next bit:

```
 // 1 if 3d bit is set, 0 otherwise
 player = (low >> 3) & 1;
```

Or if you have number `5` - index from the *left end* and assuming `low` being `byte`:

```
 player = (low >> (sizeof(byte) * 8 - 5)) & 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to left shift the One and & with your variable.

```
player = (1 << 4) & low;
```

This will give you the 5th binary digit with trailing zeros.

```
player = ((1 << 4) & low) >> 4;
```

This gives the exact 5th binary Digit, removing the Trailing Zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shifting bits, you can simply use a bitwise AND. As others said, you are looking at the 3rd bit from the right (zero-based), in other words, at the bit that represents 2^3.

```
player = (low & 8) / 8;
```

A more generic solution would be

```
private int GetBit(int number, int bit) => (number & (1 << bit)) / (1 << bit);
```

Note: This does require casting your `decimal` to `int` since `&` doesn't work with `decimal`s.

Comment: `2 ^ bit` is `2` **xor** `bit` which is *not correct* (the easiest *counter example* is `bit = 2` - check for the second bit when `2 ^ bit == 0` and `/ (2 ^ bit)` throws exception). You, probably, mean `Pow(2, bit)` which can be implemented as `1 << bit`

Comment: `(number & (1 << bit)) / (1 << bit)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes, that was a stupid oversight, I did mean pow(2, bit) of course!

Comment: `(number & (1 << bit))  >> bit` should be better than division